# Unable to find entity with id even if it exists

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, jpa

I have two entities, AppUser and Course
One AppUser can create many Courses
so this is my code :
Class AppUser :

```
@Entity(name = "users")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AppUser {

   /**
     * ID of the user
     *
     * type : UUID
     */
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private UUID userId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Course> courses;
```

Class Course :

```
@Entity(name = "course")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Course {

/**
 * ID of the course
 *
 * type: UUID
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "course_id")
private UUID courseId;

/**
 * The creator of the course
 *
 * type: AppUser
 */

@ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "createdBy")
private AppUser createdBy;
```

Lombok annotation (data, AllArgs.. ) I don't need to use setters, getters, toString, Constructs.

when I call the repository from a local function with @Transactional , it works without issue :

```
@Transactional
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        appFixtures.load();
        Course  x =  courseRepository.findByName("Angular X Firebase");
        System.out.println("created by"+x.getCreatedBy().getEmail());
    }
```

but when I call it from a webService; even if there is @Transactional annotation, it gives an error :

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class CourseController {

    @Autowired
    private CourseRepository courseRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/course", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Transactional
    public Collection<Course> getCourses(Pageable pageable){
        return courseRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

this is the error received by the client, even if the showen ID exists :

```
{"timestamp":"2018-08-27T13:05:36.980+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Unable to find fr.gfi.elearningapispring.entities.AppUser with id deb859d9-409e-4310-b96d-fc11656bd6f7; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find fr.gfi.elearningapispring.entities.AppUser with id deb859d9-409e-4310-b96d-fc11656bd6f7","path":"/course"}
```

this is the error in the console :

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find fr.gfi.elearningapispring.entities.AppUser with id deb859d9-409e-4310-b96d-fc11656bd6f7
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1240) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1123) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:171) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1152) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1011) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:72) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:307) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at fr.gfi.elearningapispring.web.CourseController.getCourses(CourseController.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at fr.gfi.elearningapispring.web.CourseController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7eb9b15.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:746) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at fr.gfi.elearningapispring.web.CourseController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cd85c563.getCourses(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at fr.gfi.elearningapispring.security.JWTAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTAuthorizationFilter.java:90) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: Looks like there is no user with that ID in the database: AppUser with id deb859d9-409e-4310-b96d-fc11656bd6f7

Comment: it exists in the database, cuz when I call the local function it load all user, but the webservice gives the error, I think @Transactional doesn't work with webservice

Comment: @Hamza what happens if you try to execute a simple SQL query from your SQL workbench? What is the result for selecting the user by id?

Comment: it doesn't return any row,

Comment: I add in the local function this line : 
System.out.println("created by"+x.getCreatedBy().getUserId());
and when I search in SQL workbench for the ID, I cannot find it.
it's weird

Comment: @dbl I changed the ID type from UUID to Long, and it works.
but in this project, I must work with UUID

Comment: @Hamza what DB are you using? What is the table definition for "users"? Try this: select * from users where id = unhex('my-custom-uuid-here');

Comment: Just forgot to tell u that you should remove all the dashes before unhexing!

Comment: @dbl I'm using MySQL db, I tried the function but it doesn't work.
I think the problem come, when the UUID is used as foreign key.

Comment: Then what does this query returns: select hex(user_id) from users; Have you tried adding proper getters and setters for both the classes?

Comment: @Hamza *I think `@Transactional` doesn't work with webservice* It works also with webservices. Maybe you use a n other db when calling it localy and when you call the webservice?

Comment: I think the issue cuz uuid field are saved as blob in the database.

Comment: @Hamza Did u find any answer??

Answer (score 3):

Just in order if anyone is still looking for it. I had the same issue in my project, but in my case Hibernate was automatically translating `UUID` field of Entity into `BINARY(255)` column type. I had no problems retrieving rows with `findAll()` method of repository, but when I tried to retrieve anything by id, passing it to the `@RestController` (a REALLY existing id) the following exception always occured:

```
No class {Your entity class} entity with id {Your UUID} exists!
```

I checked several projects which probably were working properly and found following definition for column type:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
private UUID id;
```

or:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "VARBINARY(16)")
private UUID id;
```

And it also worked in my case. If I'm not mistaken, the problem with `BINARY(255)` occurs when passing UUID is being compared with the UUID from the database, which has trailing bytes (the zero bytes, to simply fit the size of 255 bytes, because UUID is only 16 bytes long) and which are not being truncated during the retrieval. Obviously, there are no problems with `VARBINARY(16)` (or even `VARBINARY(255)`, though its redundant) because it's simply takes the size of input value. The [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/binary-varbinary.html) explain it well:

> When BINARY values are stored, they are right-padded with the pad value to the specified length. The pad value is 0x00 (the zero byte). Values are right-padded with 0x00 for inserts, and no trailing bytes are removed for retrievals. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including ORDER BY and DISTINCT operations. 0x00 and space differ in comparisons, with 0x00 sorting before space.

> Example: For a BINARY(3) column, 'a ' becomes 'a \0' when inserted. 'a\0' becomes 'a\0\0' when inserted. Both inserted values remain unchanged for retrievals.

> For VARBINARY, there is no padding for inserts and no bytes are stripped for retrievals. All bytes are significant in comparisons, including ORDER BY and DISTINCT operations. 0x00 and space differ in comparisons, with 0x00 sorting before space.

And in the end:

> If the value retrieved must be the same as the value specified for storage with no padding, it might be preferable to use VARBINARY or one of the BLOB data types instead.

Comment: Thank you @Aleksych4, it helped a lot! Didn't find it anywhere else!

Answer (score 0):

`add in the local function this line : System.out.println("created by"+x.getCreatedBy().getUserId()); and when I search in SQL workbench for the ID, I cannot find it. it's weird`

It's likely then that you have persisted the `Entity` but you have not committed the transaction. Even if you flush data is not saved to the database until transaction commit. ACID principles.

So,

```
begin transaction
write data
read with query // returns nothing
commit transaction.
```

Is wrong. You need to

```
begin transaction
write data
commit transaction
read data
```

Comment: I'm working with spring, it save data in the db, but I don't know why it save uuid as blob in the db

Comment: K.Nicholas you are not in the right direction here. The entity is persisted and therefore Hibernate tries to retrieve it from the DB by ID. In this case the problem is with finding "ANY" of the persisted object since casting from DB contained type and JAVA DAO member type. @Hamza we can not help you until you provide here the DB description for the table. Use the following command in your mysql cli to provide the info for us : *describe users;*.

Comment: this is the table : 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1sAZnM2o9EaBCcwvyWxNNCrop9hDksYCL

Answer (score 0):

Change your

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

**to**

```
*@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy="createdBy")*
```

Answer (score 0):

add these methods in courseRepository.java

```
@Override
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "createdBy")
List<Course> findAll();

@Override
@EntityGraph(attributePaths = "createdBy")
Page<Course> findAll(Pageable var1);
```